# How to put a function in a foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T] (
   [A]        NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
   [B]        NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
   [C]        BIT            NOT NULL,
   [D]        INT            NOT NULL,
   [E]        DATETIME       NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.T] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (A,B,C)
);
```

And partially another one:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[W] (
   [A]      INT IDENTITY(1,1),
   [B]      NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
   [C]      BIT            NOT NULL,
   [D]      INT            NOT NULL,
   [E]     TIME        NULL,
   [F]      TIME           NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.W] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([A] ASC),
   CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.W_T] FOREIGN KEY(PARSENAME(REPLACE([B], '_', '.'), 2), PARSENAME(REPLACE([B], '_', '.'), 1), [C]) REFERENCES T(A,B,C) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This doesn't work because it won't allow me to put a function into a foreign key constraint.

`T.A_T.B` is equal to `W.B`

I am trying to say that all `W` must match a `T` where `W.B` equals `CONCAT(T.A, '_', T.B)` and `W.C` equals  `T.C`

Then if a record in `T` is deleted all of the associated `W` based off of the foreign key should be deleted.

Comment: This is really a strange "foreign key" but you can accomplish this by using a persisted computed column.

Comment: Actually given the nature of what you have going on here I don't know that you can accomplish this because to persist a computed column it has to be deterministic.

Comment: @Sean Lange - That's the error I got when publishing from VS.

Comment: Do you have to use the parsename function if you create multiple computed columns in table W? Can you just create them using string functions (are all deterministic) like replace and substring? If you can get rid of PARSENAME then it would be deterministic - [list of deterministic and nondeterministic functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: okay, I'll try that

Comment: Maybe you should consider fixing the data model so you don't have to jump through these hurdles. It seems that you are violating 1NF by shoving multiple pieces of data into a single tuple which is causing you all the hassle.

Comment: @Anssssss that seems to be working thanks.

Comment: @Sean Lange I'll see if I can fix the data model. I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree that this is the best idea (Far from it), but you *could* reinvent the wheel and make a deterministic version of `PARSENAME`, and then create a `PERSISTED` column on  that:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_parsename (@ObjectName nvarchar(386), @PartNum tinyint)
RETURNS sysname
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @PartName sysname;
    SELECT @PartName = SUBSTRING(@ObjectName,
                                 CASE @PartNum WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                               WHEN 2 THEN one.CI+1
                                               WHEN 3 THEN two.CI+1   
                                               WHEN 4 THEN three.CI+1
                                 END,
                                 CASE @PartNum WHEN 1 THEN one.CI-1
                                               WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL(two.CI -1,LEN(obj)) - one.CI
                                               WHEN 3 THEN ISNULL(three.CI -1,LEN(obj)) - two.CI
                                               WHEN 4 THEN ISNULL(four.CI -1,LEN(obj)) - three.CI
                                 END) 
    FROM (VALUES(@ObjectName)) V(Obj)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.',V.obj),0))) one(CI)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.',V.obj,one.CI+1),0))) two(CI)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.',V.obj,two.CI+1),0))) three(CI)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.',V.obj,three.CI+1),0))) four(CI);

    RETURN @PartName;
END;



GO
CREATE TABLE Test (ObjectName nvarchar(386),
                   DatabaseName AS dbo.fn_parsename(ObjectName,1) PERSISTED)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Test (ObjectName)
VALUES('Sandbox.dbo.Test'),
      ('AdventureWorks2012.Person.Address');
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Test;

GO        

DROP TABLE Test;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_parsename;
```

Comment: Using left and right with a char index seems to have worked for me. Thanks anyway